# How to configure PythonPath in apache2

Tags: python, apache2

The default version of Python in my Ubuntu(12.04) is 2.7 .
For python2.7 projects,I am configuring like this:

```
 <Location "/callcentre">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE callcentre.settings
    PythonInterpreter callcentre
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/home/user/env/callcentreENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages','/home/user/env/callcentreENV/'] + sys.path"
  </Location>
```

And it is working perfectly.

Now what I want is to create a new project using python3.2 . And I don't know how to configure it in appache as the sys.path is pointing to default python2.7